# Python IndexError: list index out of range in cleaning up a file using CSV module

Tags: python, django, csv

I have to cleanup some files before doing the import into the Django's DB. I have an error as per the title saying that the index is out of range. My files have many rows, some of them have 10.000 rws or others have more.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cohen/my-python-project/venv/ofac/ofac_project/ofac_sdn/import_save/cleanup_sdn.py", line 9, in <module>
    replaced7 = row[7].replace('-0-', newinteger)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How can i fix this error? Despite the error pops up, the first file is cleaned up, but the rest of them are not.

Thank you in advance!

Please find below my code:

```
import csv, os, sys
newstring = "null"
newinteger = str(0)
newstring1= "null"
newstring2= "null"
newstring3= "null"
with open('sdn.csv', 'r') as file1, open('new_sdn.csv', 'w', newline='') as file2:
    reader = csv.reader(file1, delimiter=',')
    writer = csv.writer(file2, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        replaced7 = row[7].replace('-0-', newinteger)
        row[7]=replaced7
        replaced8 = row[8].replace('-0-', newinteger)
        row[8]=replaced8
        replaced2 = row[2].replace('-0-', newstring)
        row[2] = replaced2
        replaced4 = row[4].replace('-0-', newstring)
        row[4] = replaced4
        replaced5 = row[5].replace('-0-', newstring)
        row[5] = replaced5
        replaced6 = row[6].replace('-0-', newstring)
        row[6] = replaced6
        replaced9 = row[9].replace('-0-', newstring)
        row[9] = replaced9
        replaced10 = row[10].replace('-0-', newstring)
        row[10] = replaced10
        replaced11 = row[11].replace('-0-', newstring)
        row[11] = replaced11
        writer.writerow(row)

with open('add.csv', 'r') as file3, open('new_add.csv', 'w', newline='') as file4:
    reader1 = csv.reader(file3, delimiter=',')
    writer1 = csv.writer(file4, delimiter=',')
    for line in reader1:
        replaced12 = line[2].replace('-0-', newstring1)
        line[2] = replaced12
        replaced13 = line[3].replace('-0-', newstring1)
        line[3] = replaced13
        replaced14 = line[4].replace('-0-', newstring1)
        line[4] = replaced14
        replaced15 = line[5].replace('-0-', newstring1)
        line[5] = replaced15
        writer1.writerow(line)

with open('alt.csv', 'r') as file5, open('new_alt.csv', 'w', newline='') as file6:
    reader2 = csv.reader(file5, delimiter=',')
    writer2 = csv.writer(file6, delimiter=',')
    for rand in reader2:
        replaced16 = rand[2].replace('-0-', newstring2)
        rand[2] = replaced16
        replaced17 = rand[3].replace('-0-', newstring2)
        rand[3] = replaced17
        replaced18 = rand[4].replace('-0-', newstring2)
        rand[4] = replaced18
        writer2.writerow(rand)

with open('sdn_comments.csv', 'r') as file7, open('new_sdn_comments.csv', 'w', newline='') as file8:
    reader3 = csv.reader(file7, delimiter=',')
    writer3 = csv.writer(file8, delimiter=',')
    for linie in reader3:
        replaced19 = linie[1].replace('-0-', newstring3)
        linie[1] = replaced19
        writer3.writerow(linie)
```

I have split the cleanup codes in 4 and in all 4 i have this error on different column etc.

Comment: Sorry for my first comment. I completely oversaw the main problem: `row` in your case is the element of your row content. `row` is indead the row that is read in `reader` and cannot have an item like `row[7]` or even `row[0]` (oh, well, you'd get single characters of the string I assume). You could instead store the content of your file in a list and then replace your stuff.

Comment: @offeltoffel maybe you should read the csv module's doc before posting ? Here rows are lists, not strings.

Comment: sorry, my bad. I confused it with the read-function. Still, the error means that `rows` does not have an element with index 7. Maybe a matter of the input data which we cannot assess without seeing it...

Comment: First point: you should open your files in binary mode ("rb" and "wb") as documented. Second point: if the problem persists, it means some of your files have missing columns, so you will have to take care of it - either by rejecting the file as invalid or by not processing missing columns (or by adding them as empty/default values).  You can check the number of elements in a row before processing it, or you can use try/excepts blocks. The first thing I'd do would be to wrap the replacement code (the parts within the for loops) with a try/except and print out the row (and linenum) in the except

Comment: Also - partly unrelated but anyway: there are a lot of useless repetitions in your code. You could factor out all the replacement parts with `replace(row, index, target, newval)`  function and for each source file have a mapping of index=>replacement so you can use an inner loop to do the replacements.

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue. On my last row i have a code from the export of the database. That code looks like that: `['\x1a']`therefore i wrote the code from below in order to delete the last row.

```
readFile1 = open("sdn.csv")
lines1 = readFile1.readlines()
readFile1.close()
w1 = open("sdn.csv", 'w')
w1.writelines([item for item in lines1[:-1]])
w1.close()

readFile2 = open("add.csv")
lines2 = readFile2.readlines()
readFile2.close()
w2 = open("add.csv",'w')
w2.writelines([item for item in lines2[:-1]])
w2.close()

readFile3 = open("alt.csv")
lines3 = readFile3.readlines()
readFile3.close()
w = open("alt.csv",'w')
w.writelines([item for item in lines3[:-1]])
w.close()
```